# Не работает Button jquey в Mozila

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

В хроме button работает. В мозиле не хочет.
Возможно проблема в допустимом синтаксисе для мозила. Никак не пойму в чем проблема.

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  if ($(".next_but button").is(":disabled")) {
    // 
  } else {
    $(".order").css("display", "none");
    $(".customer").css("display", "block");
    $(".resume").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.next_but {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.next_but button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.next_but button:active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next_but">
  <button disabled><img src="img/button_next_disable.png" alt="Далее" id="next"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: вроде все норм https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение своей проблеме!

Причина по которой нажатие на кнопку не обрабатывается в mozila заключается в том, что я повесил обработчик события не на саму кнопку, а на картинку (тег img) находящейся внутри этой кнопки!

Было:

```html
<button disabled><img src="img/button_next_disable.png" alt="Далее" id="next"></button>
```

А нужно:

```html
<button disabled id="next"><img src="img/button_next_disable.png" alt="Далее"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере FF не отрабатывает событие click на кнопке с атрибутом disabled

> Firefox и, возможно, другие браузеры, отключают DOM-события в полях формы, которые отключены. Любое событие, которое начинается в отключенном поле формы, полностью отменяется и не распространяется на дерево DOM.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробовал убрать disabled - это не помогло(

Comment: @AzadMamedov там просто походу еще картинка не подтягивалась и не попадала на клик мышки, потому на ней клик и не отрабатывал. А то что на одной из версий FF заработало с disabled не факт что на всех будет. И логика на самом деле понятна - отключен значит отключен.